# Подключение System.Drawing в dll библиотеку С#

Tags: c#, исключения, dll, ссылки

Делаю динамическое подключение классов и возникла необходимость вынести код в dll библиотеку.

По умолчанию System.Drawing.dll не подключается к библиотеке классов и поэтому :

  1) Установил ссылку на System.Drawing.dll

  2) Использовал using System.Drawing;

После этого при компиляции выдает ошибку:

"SDK невозможно определить корневую папку "Portable 7.0". See 
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798187
for more information."

Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Вероятно, вы создаёте portable class library? Если да, то там нельзя использовать `System.Drawing`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, видимо так. Чтобы использовать System.Drawing необходимо создавать Class Library (.NET Core) ?

Comment: Скачал vs17, все скомпилировалось без ошибок.